# Should persistence tests depend on the data access layer implementation?

Tags: object-oriented, database, testing

Currently we are developing the data access layer of a CRUD application. We have the following structure:

- We have business entities which are used outside the data access layer to perform the business logic.
- We have DAO entities which are used in the data access layer to store the data in our database. These entities are only data objects that map one to one to our database tables. They live inside our data access layer and cannot be used outside of this layer.
- We have a class, let’s call it `DatabaseAPI`, responsible which offers the crud API for our business entities. For example it has the method `EntityX createEntityX(EntityX entityToCreate)` where `EntityX` is a business entity. This method is responsible for transforming the entity received into the corresponding DAO entities (some business entities map to more than one DAO entity), save the DAO entities and transform and return the resulting DAO entities back into the business entity.

We are currently having a discussion on how to properly test the `DatabaseAPI` methods. Particularly we have the following restriction: `EntityX` has a name field, there cannot exist two `EntityX`s with the same name. This restriction is enforced by the `DatabaseAPI` (currently as a unique constraint in our database, but we could use a query inside a transaction to check it manually), therefore we are adding a test to check that such restriction is correctly enforced, however we have the following disagreement:

- I think the test should create an `EntityX` with a given name `Y` using the method `createEntityX`. Then try to create another `EntityX` using the same name `Y`, again with method `createEntityX`, and check that it fails with the correct exception.
- My coworker thinks we should create an `EntityXDAO`, the correspondig DAO entity (or entities if there is more than one), with name `Y` in the test (manually, as `DatabaseAPI` methods don’t accept DAO entities in it's API by design). Then try to create another `EntityX` using the same name `Y`, this time using method `createEntityX`, and check that it fails with the correct exception.

So basically, we disagree on the test setup. My reasoning is:

- The DAO entities are an implementation detail and should be avoided on the tests.
- The restriction we are testing is about `EntityX`, not about `EntityXDAO`. Therefore, the test should be on terms of `EntityX`.
- We already have a previous test which checks that `createEntityX` correctly creates an `EntityX` when there are no conflicts.

My coworker’s reasoning is:

- In my proposed test, we would be using the method `createEntityX` do the test setup and then using it again for the actual test, checking that `createEntityX` throws the correct exception if an entity with the given name already exists.

The question is, should our test setup use the `createEntityX` method in its setup? Should we manually create the required DAO entities? Are there any alternative we are missing?

**Example code:**

```
void myTest()
{
    EntityX entityToCreateInDatabase = instantiateBusinessEntityX()
    databaseAPI.createEntityX(entityToCreateInDatabase)
    Assertions.assertThrows(MyDuplicityError.class, () -> databaseAPI.createEntityX(entityToCreateInDatabase))
}

void coworkersTest()
{
    EntityX entityToCreateInDatabase = instantiateBusinessEntityX()
    databaseAPI.getEntityDAO<EntityXDAO, Long>().create(new EntityXDAO(entityToCreateInDatabase))
    Assertions.assertThrows(MyDuplicityError.class, () -> databaseAPI.createEntityX(entityToCreateInDatabase))
}
```

Comment: There's something not quite right with your prose.  The phrase "we would be using `createEntityX` to test `createEntityX`" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: In any case, this would be a better question if we saw both test examples in code.  Overall it's a good description, and would be even better if it accompanied the code.

Comment: When I saw "The DAO entities are an implementation detail and should be avoided on the tests,"  my first reaction was "not if it's an integration test," and my second reaction was "Do you intend to test the DAO entities?"

Comment: Finally, mocking out the code that deals with the database in order to isolate a layer for testing is a perfectly valid technique.

Comment: I do not quite understand the reason behind this "test". How is this different from testing, that unique constraints of your DB is working? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ThomasJunk it's different since the code is doing the check here, so it's all internal and does not depend on the DB. The DB could actually be a local sqlite file, or even JSON for that matter. That check should still be there and fully functional.

Comment: Are you testing duplicate calls of `databaseAPI.createEntityX(entityToCreateInDatabase)`?  If that's the case, I would expect to see that in the test code... i.e. `myTest()`.  I might argue that even having the `getEntityDAO<EntityXDAO, Long>()` method would be exposing internal state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about **what** you're testing which could explain why you disagree on **how** to test.

You state :

> therefore we are adding a test to check that such restriction is
>   correctly enforced

You're testing that when the **external data source** used by `DatabaseAPI` says `EntityX` with name `Y` already exists, `DatabaseAPI` should throw an exception. This **external data source** says `EntityX` with name `Y` already exists by actually returning a `DAO` corresponding to the `EntityX` you're looking for (at least up to its name).

So, you could simply do this :

```
void myTest()
{
    Mock dataSourceMock = mock(DataSourceInterface)
    when(dataSourceMock)->receive('findEntityX')->with('name', 'Y')->return(new EntityXDAO(entityToCreateInDatabase))
    DatabaseAPI databaseAPI = instantiateDatabaseAPI(dataSourceMock)
    Assertions.assertThrows(MyDuplicityError.class, () -> databaseAPI.createEntityX(entityToCreateInDatabase))
}
```

Where `DataSourceInterface` should be implemented by your actual database layer which does queries.

Comment: I really like this approach, but I feel it has a minor problem. Currently we are checking this restriction using a unique constraint as a said in the question, it looks like this test doesn’t work if the validation is not done in code. We of course could mock another method of the `DataSourceInterface` to make it work in that case, probably `createEntityX`. But we would like the test to keep working regardless of if we are checking it in code or using a database constraint or another mechanism.

Comment: So that's another test. An integration test that's using your `DataSourceInterface` implementation and which needs the database to work. Testing something else means another test.